# Traffic Simulation in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, traffic

I have several line layers in QGIS 2.8.3. I want to simulate traffic flow in this. Is there a plugin or any possibilty to run a traffic simulation on it.

Comment: What has your research prior to posting uncovered?  Where have you looked?

Comment: You can draw static representation of traffic flow, anyway there are several software that can provide for dynamic or static similation

Comment: @PolyGeo thanks for prompting with your comment. I have figured out a way to do a basic simulation. I will be posting it soon.

Comment: @Ale do you know any open source/ free software?

Comment: @mapperx I know several of them but none with free license

Answer (score 2):

Found a simple way to simulate traffic by animating the lines which the represented the traffic path. I am running QGIS 2.8.3 Wien.
The first thing is to create and prepare the lines which represents the traffic path. Once this is completed, MMQGIS provides a functionality for animation. The option i choose here is Animate Lines. (**Note MMQGIS is a plugin that must be installed**)
To animate click 
**MMQGIS -> Animate -> Animate Lines**.

Choose the layer you want animated, specify the number of frames and choose where the output file (animation) should be stored. Click okay and wait for it to run. Once completed a message is shown on the lower left corner of the QGIS window, it shows it has rendered the number of frames that was set.

The next step is to copy the files into an image (all the image frames "**PNG**") manipulation program. In this case I use GIMP. Then create the animation. The step is as follows

Click **Filters -> Animation -> Playback**
This will give a simple animation of the traffic path.
[image]

Note there is another option using Time Manager Plugin which i have not tried yet.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with the plugin TimeManager. If you have data showing timestamps then you can simulate (animate) it. Each frame is exported as PNG, which you finally sample to a movie. I use Blender for that.